# How to make user email address unique in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

i want to register user in solidity, and want every user has unique email address. if someone enter email address which already teken form other user it show error message.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest option gas-wise is to create mapping where the key is a string (the e-mail address) and the value is a bool (showing whether it's registered or not).

Then you can validate against the mapping, whether the value for the key is `true` or `false`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

contract MyContract {
    mapping (string => bool) isRegistered;
    
    function register(string memory _email) external {
        require(!isRegistered[_email], 'This e-mail is already registered');
        
        // TODO perform the registration
        
        isRegistered[_email] = true; // mark it as registered
    }
}
```

Try it out:

1. Execute the `register()` function with param `john@example.com`. It passes the `require()` statement, because `isRegistered['john@example.com']` is `false`. Then it sets the `isRegistered['john@example.com']` mapping value as `true`.
2. Execute it for the second time. It fails the `require()` statement, because `isRegistered['john@example.com']` is already `true`, and throws an exception with the `This e-mail is already registered` message.

Comment: I suggest using email hashes instead of the original strings because there is no need to store the whole string in a public blockchain for this use case.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa any idea on how to create the hash in solidity?

Comment: @AndrewMiracle You can use the built-in `keccak256()` function ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions)).